# jquery load and slideDown doesn't work together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a problem with two functions that work perfectly alone but not together.
I've a function to make a dynamic menu and another to load a page in a div.

When I click on a link in the menu, my page load correctly in the good div but it seems to stop the Slide function. And so, I don't see my sousmenu.

I'm a beginner in coding and I spent a lot of time to try to solve it. I tryed to make my load with $.ajax but the result is the same.

Thanks for your help!

```js
//menu accordeon
jQuery().ready(function() {
  $('.menu').next('.sousmenu').hide();
  $('.menu').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).next(".sousmenu").is(":hidden")) {
      $('.menu').next(".sousmenu:visible").slideUp();
      $(this).next(".sousmenu").slideDown();
    }
  });
  return true;

});


//loadPage
function loadPage(urlToLoad) {
  $('#page').load(urlToLoad);

};
```

```css
.menu,
.menu-item {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a {
  color: #ababab;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:hover {
  color: #757575;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.menu a.active {
  color: #757575;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.sousmenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 0.6em;
}
.sousmenu:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sousmenu a {
  color: #ababab;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sousmenu a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #757575;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu" class="col-2">
  <?php foreach($menu as $menuitem): ?>
  <ul class="menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadPage('../page/<?=$menuitem['wnicename'] ;?>')">
      <?=$ menuitem[ 'name']; ?>
    </a>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sousmenu">
    <?php foreach($sousmenu as $sousmenuitem): if ($sousmenuitem[ 'id_parent']==$ menuitem[ 'id']){ echo "<li>"; echo "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\ " onclick=\"loadPage( '"../page/" . $sousmenuitem['wnicename '] . "');\ ">"; echo $sousmenuitem[ 'name'];
    echo "</a></li>"; }?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
<!--mainmenu-->
<div id="page" class="col-12">
</div>
<!--page-->
```

Comment: Error in console? FYI, an anchor cannot be direct descendant of `ul` element. Wrap it in LI

Comment: show the code which gives you the error  .

Comment: I've these errors in the console. "L'utilisation d'XMLHttpRequest de façon synchrone sur le fil d'exécution principal est obsolète à cause de son impact négatif sur la navigation de l'utilisateur final. Consulter http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ pour plus d'informations. jQuery.js:9625:0"
AND "NetworkError: A network error occurred. <inconnu>"

Comment: It's the function load which makes the error in console ""L'utilisation d'XMLHttpRequest de façon synchrone sur le fil d'exécution principal est obsolète à cause de son impact négatif sur la navigation de l'utilisateur final. Consulter xhr.spec.whatwg.org pour plus d'informations." meaning " The use of XMLHttpRequest in a synchronous way on the main thread of execution is obsolete because of its negative impact on the user's browsing. Consult xhr.spec.whatwg.org for more information."

Comment: @ A. Wolff, I put my anchor in a <li>, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Hi everyone! I found the solution! I moved my line which call my jquery library and my external javascript file. They were in the <head>...</head> and I put them just before my </body> All is working perfectly now!!!

Comment: In fact, I found the real problem. It was because of a double call. When My Page was loaded in my div #page, there was a <header> in it. So my header was called twice. I replaced my called javascript in the header and all works and is cleaned!!!